# Web API Json Deserialise

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web Api.

I have an object of type A. when I return a list of type A to my client and then pass the list of type A back using a Post method the JSON serialisation and deserialisation is done automatically form me.

Because I want to pass multiple parameters using my POST method I have created a wrapper object with properties for each of the parameters I want to pass in. The JSON ser / DeSer is taken care of for this wrapper object, but how do I deserialise the JSON that represents my list of Type A within the wrapper object?

Thanks.

Added Code:

```
public class ConfigurationUpdateMessage
{
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }

    public List<object> Configurations { get; set; }
}
```

The Post method

```
  public string PutUpdateConfigurations(ConfigurationUpdateMessage configMessage)   
    {}
```

Client Code

```
$scope.UpdateConfigs = function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'api/configurations',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "PUT",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ IpAddress: "127.0.0.1", Configurations: $scope.configs }),
                    async: true,
                    processData: false,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {

                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {

                    }
                });

            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRE: Can you post some code?

If your wrapper object contains properties which match the types of the serialized objects the model binder should automatically deserialize them into the matching properties. Unless there's something wrong with the structure of the JSON you're POSTing.

Comment: I found the problem. It was because my wrapper object had the list decared as List<object> and I should have declared it as List<A> now the deser is taken care of automatically. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your same wrapper type on server-side.

For example:

```
public class OperationDTO
{
     public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
     public int Parameter2 { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<A> MyList { get; set; } //List<A> will also work too
}
```

Your Web Api action should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Operation([FromBody] OperationDTO)
{
    //...
}
```